# Using the Eclipse Marketplace on Aptana Studio 3

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, aptana

I'm currently trying out Aptana Studio 3 for PHP development (I'm pretty new to all these), and I've stumbled upon a problem. I've noticed Eclipse has a Marketplace that hosts a wide variety of plugins, and I'd like to install one that helps me for version control.

However, I can't find the Eclipse Marketplace dialog under Aptana. Is there anybody out there who's done this before (installing Eclipse Marketplace stuff in Aptana)?

Also, this is a little out-of-topic but I'd like to use Java.net as the place where I'll be storing my repository. To my knowledge, NetBeans has a built-in support for Java.net; is there anything similar for Eclipse/Aptana Studio?

**EDIT:** If it helps, I installed Aptana Studio as a standalone version, and not as a plugin on Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Help / Install New Software, and click on the Available Software Sites link. You'll probably have the eclipse Helios release directory in the list, just check it to activate it. A lot of third-party packages have their own release sites, you can add them in the same dialog.

Comment: I don't on the Aptana Studio 3 I'm running. My available software sites is empty/blank. I'll look into maybe doing an export from my eclipse and import in Aptana but I'm wondering if maybe there's a reason Aptana didn't include it by default.